# Get second and third words from string

Tags: javascript

I have strings in jQuery:

```
var string1 = 'Stack Exchange premium';
var string2 = 'Similar Questions'; //  only two
var string3 = 'Questions that may already have your answer';
```

How can i get from this second and third words?

```
var second1 = ???;
var third1 = ???;
var second2 = ???;
var third2 = ???;
var second3 = ???;
var third3 = ???;
```

Comment: You should add your code to the question. What have you tried, and why didn't it work?

Comment: When people have JavaScript problems, they say it's jQuery problem, even if the problem doesn't involve jQuery at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, you don't have strings and variables "in jQuery". jQuery has nothing to do with this.

Second, change your data structure, like this:

```
var strings = [
    'Stack Exchange premium',
    'Similar Questions',
    'Questions that may already have your answer'
];
```

Then create a new Array with the second and third words.

```
var result = strings.map(function(s) {
    return s.split(/\s+/).slice(1,3);
});
```

Now you can access each word like this:

```
console.log(result[1][0]);
```

This will give you the first word of the second result.

Answer (score 22):

Use string [`split()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) to split the string by spaces:

```
var words = string1.split(' ');
```

Then access the words using:

```
var word0 = words[0];
var word1 = words[1];
// ...
```

Comment: You shouldn't encourage the OP to use variables such as `word0`, `word1`, `wordXXX` etc.

Comment: @LeeTaylor It's just an example

Answer (score 5):

Just to add to the possible solutions, the technique using `split()` will fail if the string has multiple spaces in it.

```
var arr = "   word1   word2    ".split(' ')

//arr is ["", "", "", "word1", "", "", "word2", "", "", "", ""]
```

To avoid this problem, use following

```
var arr = "   word1   word2    ".match(/\S+/gi)

//arr is ["word1", "word2"]
```

and then the usual,

```
var word1 = arr[0];
var word2 = arr[1]
//etc
```

also don't forget to check your array length using `.length` property to avoid getting `undefined` in your variables.

Answer (score 4):

```
var temp = string1.split(" ")//now you have 3 words in temp
temp[1]//is your second word
temp[2]// is your third word
```

you can check how many words you have by temp.length

Answer (score 0):

const string = "The lake is a long way from here."

const [,second,third,] = string.split(" ");