# Return the sub string value from string

Tags: javascript, indexof, servicenow

I came from ServiceNow background. I need help to get the user name from the following string value.

"Legal Name Change Submitted for XXXXXXX : ACTION REQUIRED from IT Help Desk".

In above text XXXX refers to user name and i need to retrieve that value. It's always stays between "for" and ":". How do i do this by using javascript?

Thanks,
Chaitanya

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16223068/6092191

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest to use `match` with regular expression

```
var statement = "Legal Name Change Submitted for XXXXXXX : ACTION REQUIRED from IT Help Desk";
var submittedFor = statement.match(/for\s(.*)\s:/)[1];
console.log(submittedFor); // it will print  XXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 0):

Brute-force solution

```
const message = "Legal Name Change Submitted for XXXXXXX : ACTION REQUIRED from IT Help Desk";
const forWord = 'for';
const forIndex = message.indexOf(forWord);
const colonIndex = message.indexOf(':');
const forLength = forWord.length;

message.slice(forIndex + forLength, colonIndex).trim();
```

More elegant solution

```
const message = "Legal Name Change Submitted for XXXXXXX : ACTION REQUIRED from IT Help Desk";
const result = message.match(/(?<=for)(.*)(?=:)/);
const name = result.value[0].trim();
```